# Special chracter updated instead of apostrophe in ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle, special-characters, insert-update

While updating in oracle "Driver's "got converted into "Driverâ€™s License".

I have a code which creates a select query and handles apostrophe and it creates the right query but while executing the query characters has been changed.

Comment: Can you paste your code here

Comment: Sounds like character set conversion, starting from a curly-quote like `’` rather than a straight quote. Could be a display issue rather than a data issue - you can use the dump function to check what is actually stored. Then you need to look at the DB, client/app and OS/terminal character set settings.